# Navigations Bars Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, navigation

I followed this example on [wc3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_navbars.asp)

I tried to implement the exact code to my Project. I want the navigation bar to change pages but somehow I can not get it work. However I'm able to make the navigation bar to work if I Place a url within, like `<li><a href="http://www.google.com/"data-icon="calendar">Google</a></li>`.

My question is if navbars can be used between Jquery mobile pages and if it is possible, what am I doing wrong? Would be nice with a working example!

Comment: JQM uses ajax for navigation to its pages. Check the docs for linking to external domains (URL'S). http://api.jquerymobile.com/data-attribute/ -- scroll down to Link. you need to use (data-rel="external")

Answer (score 0):

There is some excellent documentation including examples available at the jQuery Mobile demos pages.  The specific link to the NavBar docs can be found [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.4/navbar/).  I'd suggest having a read at these documents.

In summary however, a navigation bar is is a `<div>` with a data-role of "navbar" that contains an `<ul>` list where each button in the navbar is a `<li>` which does indeed contain an anchor `<a>` tag which defines where a click of the specific button will take you.